# stroke-dasharray can't bind with angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, stroke-dasharray

I used this Chart with angular 6 , I faced the some conflict on this chart, i try to bind data , but i cant do that, its not working correctly,

This `stroke-dasharray="5, 100"` to I replaced   this one 
`stroke-dasharray="{{this.master.locationVsStatusMap.size}}, 100"`

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aenvso)

anyone know how to do that correctly ?

Thanks in advance!

```css
.single-chart {
  width: 33%;
  justify-content: space-around ;
}

.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #3c9ee5;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3.8;border-right: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white;
  stroke-linecap:square;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}

.circular-chart.orange .circle {
  stroke: #ff9f00;border-right: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.circular-chart.green .circle {
  stroke: #4CC790;
}

.circular-chart.blue .circle {
  stroke: #3c9ee5;
}

.percentage {
  fill: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.3em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
<div class="single-chart">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
    <path class="circle-bg"
          d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
    />
    <path class="circle"
          stroke-dasharray="5, 100"
          d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
    />
      <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">50%</text>
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz to reproduce the issue?

Comment: try to call a method there which returns a string 5, 100. [stroke-dasharray]="getXXX()"

Comment: Could you also show a sample of your Angular component code that sets the bindings?

Comment: @Justcode , Hi I updated my question, can you please recheck my issue?

Comment: @PavanShukla  I tried but not working

Comment: @ShaiAharoni please look my updated, I added `stackblitz` code link

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try attribute binding

```
attr.stroke-dasharray="{{this.master.locationVsStatusMap.size}}, 100"
```

Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqjlc5

Ref this: https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thanks you save me

Answer (score 4):

Use **style** binding - https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-progress-component-with-svg

```
style.stroke-dasharray="{{varible}}, 100"
```